# How can users launch internal activites

Tags: android, android-intent

I have got 3 identical crash reports on GooglePlay, where the stack trace looks as if the users directly launched an internal activity (which has no intent-filter for category LAUNCHER set in the manifest).

Is there a way to do that, which I missed so far? Can one create a kind of shortcut from the current activity and use it later on to directly launch that activity?

Here is the stack-trace from GooglePlay:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eb.ohrh.parawind.free/eb.wind.activity.logbook.LogBookSingleDispActivity}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1728)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1747)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at eb.wind.views.mapv2.MapWithOverlay.isFlightMode(MapWithOverlay.java:599)
at eb.wind.views.mapv2.MapWithOverlay.bindToModel(MapWithOverlay.java:335)
at eb.wind.activity.logbook.LogBookSingleDispActivity$MyPagerAdapter.<init>(LogBookSingleDispActivity.java:189)
at eb.wind.activity.logbook.LogBookSingleDispActivity.onCreate(LogBookSingleDispActivity.java:39)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1692)
... 11 more`

LogBookSingleDispActivity is an internal Activity. It can not be launched without some preparation steps of other activities.

Any idea, how this can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process will not live forever. If your app shows up in the recent-tasks list, but its process was terminated, when the user goes back into your app (e.g., via the recent-tasks list), Android will return the user to whatever activity they had last been on.

There are other scenarios as well where users might get to "internal" activities (e.g., from one of your `Notifications`, from one of your app widgets).

You need to make sure that your app can survive the user coming to any one of the activities. Ideally, you are using things like the `savedInstanceState` to make it appear though you had been around all along, even though the prior instance of your activity had been destroyed and your process terminated. In cases where that is not possible (e.g., you need the user to re-authenticate), there are various solutions (e.g., detect that your session was reset and use `startActivity()` to get to the user to the login activity).

Comment: I just tried the following: Navigate to the "internal" activity. Closed the app with the home button (which means, it's still running in the background and would be re-launched from the internal activity) and then forced stop the app using the application manager. If I then restart the app from the recent tasks list, it opens the default launch activity. This is exactly what I had expected. Either the last activity opens, if the app is still alive, or the launcher activity opens, if the app has been stopped by the OS. Is there another way to simulate the OS behaviour you described?

Comment: @user2808624: "and then forced stop the app using the application manager" -- Android does not have an "application manager". And if you truly mean "force stop", what is normally done via the "Force Stop" button in Settings, that is not something the user will normally do. "Is there another way to simulate the OS behaviour you described?" -- terminate the process via DDMS.

Comment: "Android does not have an 'application manager'"? Now, that is exactly the title of the settings, where Apps can be stopped. But you are right, using DDMS to stop the process results in the described behaviour.

Comment: @user2808624: "Now, that is exactly the title of the settings, where Apps can be stopped" -- on your particular device, perhaps, because your device manufacturer modified Android to use that term.